# seeing print statements from code in pytest with -s flag

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why would I be able to see print messages from source code when running a pytest with flag `-s` or `--capture=no`?

Example:

src/hello.py

```
def something():
    print('this is a test')
```

tests/test_hello.py

```
import hello
class need_to_know(TestCase):
    def test_something():
        something()
        assert True
```

out: this is a test

Comment: Pytest captures all stdout by default to hide irrelevant output and only show failing tests if any fail. By adding `-s` you tell Pytest to show you the output. Btw `-s` and `--capture=no` are equivalent.

Comment: @MaxSkoryk so why would i see the output of the print statements even without -s?

Comment: Because you still use `--capture=no`? If you just run `pytest` without flags Pytest should hide what is printed from you.

Answer (score 2):

You have the logic backwards: `-s`, which is equivalent to `--capture=no`, **disables** the capturing of output, i.e. it will be shown on your terminal instead of redirected internally (and only shown in case of an error)

Comment: Running the same code as posted in your question?